# Wordpress menu development

Tags: wordpress

I have a simple topbar menu in html.How can i get it via wordpress ? walker_nav_menu is great,but i don't know how to use it properly as a newbie in wordpress.

```
<ul class="topbar-list topbar-menu">
                        <li><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Forums</a></li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="javascript:void(0);">Dropdown</a>
                            <ul class="topbar-dropdown">
                                <li><a href="#">Dropdown</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Dropdown</a></li>
                                <li class="topbar-submenu">
                                    <a href="javascript:void(0);">Submenu</a>
                                    <ul class="topbar-submenu-in">
                                        <li><a href="#">Submenu</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#">Submenu</a></li>
                                        <li class="topbar-submenu">
                                            <a href="javascript:void(0);">Submenu</a>
                                            <ul class="topbar-submenu-in">
                                                <li><a href="#">Submenu</a></li>
                                                <li><a href="#">Submenu</a></li>
                                            </ul>
                                        </li>
                                    </ul>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li class="cd-log_reg hidden-sm hidden-md hidden-lg"><strong><a class="cd-signin" href="javascript:void(0);">Login</a></strong></li>
                        <li class="cd-log_reg hidden-sm hidden-md hidden-lg"><strong><a class="cd-signup" href="javascript:void(0);">Register</a></strong></li>
                    </ul>
```

Comment: Do you want to simply include this file as is in the theme, or add the WordPress menu options inside this structure?

Comment: I want to generate the html via walker nav class